# Magento calendar not working

Tags: magento-enterprise, orders, adminhtml, custom-options, magento-1

quite strange but is happening with me...Mag version is `EE 1.12`

- Calendar is working fine on front end
- it works fine in admin back end on normal pages see this
  [image]
- but when calendar is in pop up page, it does not work....(try
  creating an order from admin backend, add product, configure, and try
  to select date if you got some product with custom options (date-time
  picker)) ...see this 
  [image]

I am trying to solve this issue for more than a month, no success...I have tried seeing the source code, and it looks that calendar.js, calendar_setup.js and other files are includes just as those page which got working calendar on it..

Dont know should I do it or not, but to get more views and possible solutions, I asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180764/magento-calendar-not-working-on-pop-up) too

any idea?

thanks

Comment: what kind of custom option is 'Delivery date'? If I set a date (or datetime) custom option for a product I don't get the calendar button. I get dropdowns for each section of the date and time. This happens on EE 1.12 and CE 1.7.

Comment: There is a configuration option catalog/custom_options/use_calendar which controls that. The JS calendar seems to be set to "Off" on default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem on 1.8.1 and found that the z-index was empty. I'm assuming it's being attached to the dom wrong, as it's using some khtml browser speciality code.   Anyways, I got it working again by adding

> cal.element.style.zIndex = 99999;

in calendar-setup.js

like so

> else cal.showAt(params.position[0], params.position[1]);
>   cal.element.style.zIndex = 99999;
>   return false;

It's still along the left, but it works!

Comment: I can confirm that this solution is working. Just don't overwrite the original file as it will be overwritten again on next update. Create a new file and include this instead via layout xml.

Answer (score 1):

The calender popups up correct? It is there on the left side?

And if you can't click anything, there is some element over it. Did you check, whether the "blur" is over it? Open Firebug and try to click in the calender, then you selected the element which stands in your way.

Comment: I did it, but Nor I can click on calendar, neither I can find any blur,,,

Comment: Behind the popup is a 100% width, 100% height div with a white background and opacity. And my frontend friend said, there is a class missing in the popup.

Comment: so what should I do??

Comment: please suggest..

Comment: I have no idea. It is frontend stuff. Something is wrong with the HTML or CSS and without access to the system it is not debugable. Here I'm out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem for my custom theme.I added Z-Index to calender class in `styles.css` of the theme. It works fine

```
.calendar {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #d4d0c8;
border-color: #fff #000 #000 #fff;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
color: #000;
cursor: default;
display: none;
font-family: tahoma,verdana,sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: I added `.calendar { z-index:105; }` in my _skin\frontend\<mypackger>\<mytheme>\css\styles.css_ and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me

`js\calendar/calendar-setup.js`
add this following code in js file

```
 else cal.showAt(params.position[0], params.position[1]); cal.element.style.zIndex = 99999; return false;
```

`skin\adminhtml/default/default/css/tinybox/style.css`

```
.calendar { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #d4d0c8; border-color: #fff #000 #000 #fff; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; color: #000; cursor: default; }
```

anyone this issue come so we can do this
such a great helpful thanks